# React Native LruCache: Does it cache images from image urls

Tags: android, caching, react-native

Basically, I am making an API call to get some kind of response back. In this response, there is some field like `socialImageUrl` that points to a URL string that references an image. There is other data there besides the URL. I am caching that entire response.

So I turn off wifi and LTE, and I checked that I had no internet connection by doing stuff on the browser. I go back into my app and I trigger my LruCache and retrieved the cached response (I know I got it because of logging) and I use that response to render my page.

What I expected: I would see all the data that I cached on the page but anything that used the image URLs will give out some erroneous image or maybe the page doesn't even load at all because there is some error with that image URL seeing as it can't access the internet

What actually happens: I see all of the data I cached and I also see the images

Any clue to what is going on? I'm not doing any image caching as far as I know. I am using react-native's vanilla Image JSX component. I am also on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also in this situation ones, sadly React-Native docs are not extensive for now.

> The Android implementation of **Image** component has by default caching enabled for images of low **size < 500 KB** (the max size is not documented but you can just try images of varied size to check and this size could change in the future).

Note: Even in IOS the image's will be cached by default when using the Image component.

Comment: Where did you find the source for this. I can't find it on google. Also two more questions. One, sure the android implementation of Image has caching, but I am using React Native. I understand that React Native is bridging to Native Android, so are you saying that React Native Image jsx bridges to the Native Android Image xml tag therefore it implicitly has caching?

Comment: Two, how concerned should I be about Image tag's caching TTL to not sync up with my LRU cache of my entire JSON response. Specifically the case where the cache expires my image when my response is still cached in my LRU

Comment: 1.React-Native Image component uses Fresco library for Android, which has default image cache. I don't think so they bridge directly to native Android Image component. Also regarding the source of information, even i could not get it from google, but just search in their Github issues.

This is one such issue
[9581](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9581)

Comment: Regarding your second question I don't know the best practise in handling that case, because image cache can be cleared through various methods like user clearing it through some cleaner apps, OS clearing due to low memory etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, lru cache does not support caching binary data like an image file.

If you need advanced <Image> performance caching or for the remote image to be permanently stored to local disk for offline app use you can use my higher order component module that upgrades native <Image>

[React Native Image Cache HOC](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-image-cache-hoc)

Tl;DR Code Example:

```
import imageCacheHoc from 'react-native-image-cache-hoc';
const CacheableImage = imageCacheHoc(Image);

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <CacheableImage style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://i.redd.it/rc29s4bz61uz.png'}} />
        <CacheableImage style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://i.redd.it/hhhim0kc5swz.jpg'}} permanent={true} />
      </View>
  );
  }
}
```

The first image will be cached until the total local cache grows past 15 MB (by default) then cached images are deleted oldest first until total cache is below 15 MB again.

The second image will be stored to local disk permanently. People use this as a drop in replacement for shipping static image files with your app, but you could use it so that your app displays image content even when user is offline.

If you need to grab all the image files from the network up front (before the <CacheableImage> is rendered by react native) then just use the following CacheableImage static method to pre-fetch the files:

```
import imageCacheHoc from 'react-native-image-cache-hoc';
const CacheableImage = imageCacheHoc(Image);
CacheableImage.cacheFile('https://i.redd.it/hhhim0kc5swz.jpg', true)
  .then( localFileInfo => {
    console.log(localFileInfo);

    // Console log outputs:
    //{
    //  url: 'https://i.redd.it/rc29s4bz61uz.png',
    //  cacheType: 'permanent',
    //  localFilePath: '/this/is/absolute/path/to/file.jpg'
    //}

  });
```